# Serialization in enum

Tags: java, serialization, enums

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Object input = ABC.ad;
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("test.enum")));
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(input);
        objectOutputStream.close();

        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("test.enum")));
        Object outPut = objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();

        if(input == outPut) {
            System.out.println("Same ............"+input+" "+outPut);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

enum ABC {
    ad,de;
}
```

I am trying to serialize enum and deserialize. As expected I got the result "Same". But I dont know how its working. Even I have checked `Enum` class also. It doesnt have `readResovle` method like that. Please explain ..

Comment: `enum` is special. Did you look at the _decompiled_ code? Much code is generated by the compiler.

Comment: @BoristheSpider ya that i know enum is special. But i want to how jdk will treat enum in serialization and deserial

Comment: For all jdk its true. I want to know how

Comment: Read [the Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html).